# php how to get specific data from the variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable containing following data.

```
$cheers="<p>content:op=This is an apple</p> <p>content:op=This is a school bus</p> <p>content:op=This is PHP code</p> " ;
```

How i can get output like display below:

```
This is apple
This is school bus
This is php code
```

Thanks

Comment: This looks like something that can be easily parsed using regex.

Comment: You say "output the variable" - where? in a browser? If so just `echo $yourvariable;` would work.

Comment: but how get raid of <p>content:op=" in start and "</p> at the end...

Comment: guys i did some changings, have a look now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at parsing the string this should work for you,

```
<?php
   $cheers="<p>content:op=This is an apple</p> <p>content:op=This is a school bus</p> <p>content:op=This is PHP code</p>";
   $cheers = strip_tags($cheers);
   $arrtext = explode("content:op=", $cheers);

   foreach ($arrtext as $element){
      if ($element!=""){
            echo $element."\n\r";
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all` this => `/<[^<]+?>(.)+<[^<]+?>/`.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php
will grab everything between tags

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are displaying this on a web page and it's ready by a browser, you simply echo the value of your variable.  Not sure if you require the constant:op part which doesn't seem necessary.  it could be re-written like below.

```
    <?php
    // define variable
    $cheers="<p>content:op=This is an apple</p> <p>content:op=This is a school bus</p> <p>content:op=This is PHP code</p> " ;

    // remove extra text
    $new_cheers = str_replace("content:op=","",$cheers); 

    // split paragraphs (if needed, otherwise just echo $new_cheers)
    $paragraphs = explode(" ", $new_cheers); 
    echo $paragraphs[0]; 
    echo $paragraphs[1]; 
    echo $paragraphs[2];
    ?>
```

OPTIONAL (skip $paragraphs part above and just output new cheers below):

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Your output</h1>
<?php echo $new_cheers; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Since you already have the HTML tags the browser will read the formatting and render it properly.

Comment: If you need the colors for the words, I would instead build an array of the terms and then you control the formatting of the output.  For example $items = Array("apple", "school bus", "php code");  Then iterate through items below and add your HTML formatting in the display, not the data.  'foreach $item in $items .. <p><span class="this">This</span> <span class="is">is</span> <span class="item"><?php echo $item[$key]; ?></span></p>  ...  end foreach.

Comment: Mike my variable contain following data....

Comment: $cheers="<p>content:op=This is an apple</p> <p>content:op=This is a school bus</p> <p>content:op=This is PHP code</p> " ;

Comment: You can use substring or instead use str_replace...

See: [Php str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: 1. split the string and perhaps use explode $items = explode(" ", $cheers); // this gives you list of <p> items.

Comment: 2. iterate through the array with for loop or foreach

Comment: 3. within the loop you can use str_replace("content:op=","",$item)  (or you can do this before exploding the string in step 1 all at once)

Comment: 4. echo the output from the $item but note since it's already formatted with <p>Your text</p> you don't have the colors for each word above.  This is why I recommended you create list of items and handle the formatting of content in HTML on page and only iterate through the data.

Comment: Lastly... if you know it's only these three items... you could do this (sorry on formatting in comments is poor).

$new_cheers = str_replace("content:op=","",$cheers);
$paragraphs = explode(" ", $new_cheers);
echo $paragraphs[0];
echo $paragraphs[1];
echo $paragraphs[2];

Comment: If that works, please vote for my answer.  I'm sure the last comment will work fine, but it just depends on how flexible you want the app (whether to use a loop through the array).  Good luck!